# Post cache substitution error running locally

Tags: asp.net, lemoon

I have created a new Lemoon site on Azure Web Sites and copied it local and attempted to run it.

The database connection is still pointing to the Azure SQL database, so that should be fine.

I'm getting an error though that says...

```
"Post cache substitution is not compatible with modules in the IIS integrated pipeline that modify the response buffers.  Either a native module in the pipeline has modified an HTTP_DATA_CHUNK structure associated with a managed post cache substitution callback, or a managed filter has modified the response."
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have an IIS-module that modifies the response in some way. 
That in combination with the use of the ASP.NET Output Cache Substitution Feature causes the [error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2014472) you refer to.

The solution is to either disable the IIS-module that modifies the response or to remove the cache substitution from the master page file that ships with the Lemoon project template.

Remove the line below from the file Site.Master:

```
<!-- generated at <%= DateTime.Now.ToString("s") %> / <% Response.WriteSubstitution(RenderInfo); %> -->
```